# display a message when no content Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am using Angular/cli to create a popup body that shows a list of completed classes. The problem I am trying to solve is when there are no classes in the body I want to display a message such as "there are no completed classes". This is what I have so far.

```
   <li class="search-resultsult" *ngFor="let a of classesS">
    <div class="col col-medium">
      <div class="col col-1of2">
        <a href="#/" (click)="Play(a)">
                            <i class="ico-mic"></i>
                        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col col-1of2 -->

      <div class="col col-1of2">
        {{a.CompletedOn|date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
      </div>
      <!-- /.col col-1of2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col col-medium -->

    <div class="col col-large col-title">
      <p>{{a.Title}}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col col-medium col-title -->

    <div class="col col-medium col-speaker">
      <p>{{a.Speaker}}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col col-large col-speaker -->


    <!--<div class="col col-small">
      <a href="{{a.AudioUrl}}" class="btn btn-download" download>
                        <i class="ico-download"></i> mp3
                    </a>

    </div> -->


  </li>
  <!-- /.search-resultsult -->

</ul>
<!-- /.search-resultsults -->
```

Comment: Actually I am not getting your question, as per I understand, you want to show message when in your for loop classes have no class right?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `classesS` array will be empty, no `<li>` will be added for any of those. In order to show an `<li>` when your array is empty, simply add another one to your template using `*ngIf="!classesS.length"`:

```
<ul>

    <li class="no-search-results" *ngIf="!classesS.length">
       There are no completed classes
    </li>
    <!-- /.no-search-results -->

    <li class="search-resultsult" *ngFor="let a of classesS">
       ...
    </li>
    <!-- /.search-resultsult -->

</ul>
<!-- /.search-resultsults -->
```

Comment: thank you very much! sorry for the simple question but slowly learning angular